# I met difficulties: web3. Exceptions. Web3ValidationError:

Tags: web3.py, bridge

When I use web3.py to write a piece of code to bridge ETH from zks to op chain, I keep getting a 'deposit' method error. 
I have used the API from the Across project and written the code in the web3.py package according to the developer documentation, but no matter how I modify the code, it is still stuck in the 'deposit'.

I am a novice, I hope someone can help me

```
from web3 import Web3
import requests
import json
# from exchange_amount import exchange_amount

# 初始化 web3 对象
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://******'))

# 定义合约地址和 ABI
zkSync_SpokePool_address: str = '0xE0B015E54d54fc84a6cB9B666099c46adE9335FF'
zkSync_SpokePool_abi = [{"inputs": [], "name": "NotCrossChainCall", "type": "error"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": False, "internalType": "address", "name": "previousAdmin", "type": "address"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "address", "name": "newAdmin", "type": "address"}], "name": "AdminChanged", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": True, "internalType": "address", "name": "beacon", "type": "address"}], "name": "BeaconUpgraded", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": True, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "rootBundleId", "type": "uint256"}], "name": "EmergencyDeleteRootBundle", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": True, "internalType": "address", "name": "originToken", "type": "address"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "destinationChainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "bool", "name": "enabled", "type": "bool"}], "name": "EnabledDepositRoute", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountToReturn", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "chainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "refundAmounts", "type": "uint256[]"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "uint32", "name": "rootBundleId", "type": "uint32"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "uint32", "name": "leafId", "type": "uint32"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "address", "name": "l2TokenAddress", "type": "address"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "address[]", "name": "refundAddresses", "type": "address[]"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "address", "name": "caller", "type": "address"}], "name": "ExecutedRelayerRefundRoot", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "totalFilledAmount", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "fillAmount", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "repaymentChainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "originChainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "destinationChainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "int64", "name": "relayerFeePct", "type": "int64"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "int64", "name": "realizedLpFeePct", "type": "int64"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "uint32", "name": "depositId", "type": "uint32"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "address", "name": "destinationToken", "type": "address"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "address", "name": "relayer", "type": "address"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "address", "name": "depositor", "type": "address"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "address", "name": "recipient", "type": "address"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "bytes", "name": "message", "type": "bytes"}, {"components": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "recipient", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "bytes", "name": "message", "type": "bytes"}, {"internalType": "int64", "name": "relayerFeePct", "type": "int64"}, {"internalType": "bool", "name": "isSlowRelay", "type": "bool"}, {"internalType": "int256", "name": "payoutAdjustmentPct", "type": "int256"}], "indexed": False, "internalType": "struct SpokePool.RelayExecutionInfo", "name": "updatableRelayData", "type": "tuple"}], "name": "FilledRelay", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "originChainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "destinationChainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "int64", "name": "relayerFeePct", "type": "int64"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "uint32", "name": "depositId", "type": "uint32"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint32", "name": "quoteTimestamp", "type": "uint32"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "address", "name": "originToken", "type": "address"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "address", "name": "recipient", "type": "address"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "address", "name": "depositor", "type": "address"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "bytes", "name": "message", "type": "bytes"}], "name": "FundsDeposited", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint8", "name": "version", "type": "uint8"}], "name": "Initialized", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": True, "internalType": "address", "name": "l2Token", "type": "address"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "address", "name": "target", "type": "address"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "numberOfTokensBridged", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "l1Gas", "type": "uint256"}], "name": "OptimismTokensBridged", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": False, "internalType": "bool", "name": "isPaused", "type": "bool"}], "name": "PausedDeposits", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": False, "internalType": "bool", "name": "isPaused", "type": "bool"}], "name": "PausedFills", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": True, "internalType": "address", "name": "relayer", "type": "address"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "address", "name": "refundToken", "type": "address"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "originChainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "destinationChainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "int64", "name": "realizedLpFeePct", "type": "int64"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "uint32", "name": "depositId", "type": "uint32"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "fillBlock", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "previousIdenticalRequests", "type": "uint256"}], "name": "RefundRequested", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": True, "internalType": "uint32", "name": "rootBundleId", "type": "uint32"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "relayerRefundRoot", "type": "bytes32"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "slowRelayRoot", "type": "bytes32"}], "name": "RelayedRootBundle", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": False, "internalType": "int64", "name": "newRelayerFeePct", "type": "int64"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "uint32", "name": "depositId", "type": "uint32"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "address", "name": "depositor", "type": "address"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "address", "name": "updatedRecipient", "type": "address"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "bytes", "name": "updatedMessage", "type": "bytes"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "bytes", "name": "depositorSignature", "type": "bytes"}], "name": "RequestedSpeedUpDeposit", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint32", "name": "newBuffer", "type": "uint32"}], "name": "SetDepositQuoteTimeBuffer", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": True, "internalType": "address", "name": "newHubPool", "type": "address"}], "name": "SetHubPool", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": True, "internalType": "uint32", "name": "newL1Gas", "type": "uint32"}], "name": "SetL1Gas", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": True, "internalType": "address", "name": "l2Token", "type": "address"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "address", "name": "tokenBridge", "type": "address"}], "name": "SetL2TokenBridge", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": True, "internalType": "address", "name": "newAdmin", "type": "address"}], "name": "SetXDomainAdmin", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": False, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountToReturn", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "chainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "uint32", "name": "leafId", "type": "uint32"}, {"indexed": True, "internalType": "address", "name": "l2TokenAddress", "type": "address"}, {"indexed": False, "internalType": "address", "name": "caller", "type": "address"}], "name": "TokensBridged", "type": "event"}, {"anonymous": False, "inputs": [{"indexed": True, "internalType": "address", "name": "implementation", "type": "address"}], "name": "Upgraded", "type": "event"}, {"inputs": [], "name": "MAX_TRANSFER_SIZE", "outputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [], "name": "SLOW_FILL_MAX_TOKENS_TO_SEND", "outputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [], "name": "UPDATE_DEPOSIT_DETAILS_HASH", "outputs": [{"internalType": "bytes32", "name": "", "type": "bytes32"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "uint32", "name": "_initialDepositId", "type": "uint32"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "_crossDomainAdmin", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "_hubPool", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "_l2Eth", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "_wrappedNativeToken", "type": "address"}], "name": "__OvmSpokePool_init", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "uint32", "name": "_initialDepositId", "type": "uint32"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "_crossDomainAdmin", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "_hubPool", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "_wrappedNativeTokenAddress", "type": "address"}], "name": "__SpokePool_init", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [], "name": "chainId", "outputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [], "name": "crossDomainAdmin", "outputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "recipient", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "originToken", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "destinationChainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "int64", "name": "relayerFeePct", "type": "int64"}, {"internalType": "uint32", "name": "quoteTimestamp", "type": "uint32"}, {"internalType": "bytes", "name": "message", "type": "bytes"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "maxCount", "type": "uint256"}], "name": "deposit", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "payable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address"}], "name": "depositCounter", "outputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [], "name": "depositQuoteTimeBuffer", "outputs": [{"internalType": "uint32", "name": "", "type": "uint32"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "rootBundleId", "type": "uint256"}], "name": "emergencyDeleteRootBundle", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256"}], "name": "enabledDepositRoutes", "outputs": [{"internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "uint32", "name": "rootBundleId", "type": "uint32"}, {"components": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountToReturn", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "chainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "refundAmounts", "type": "uint256[]"}, {"internalType": "uint32", "name": "leafId", "type": "uint32"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "l2TokenAddress", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address[]", "name": "refundAddresses", "type": "address[]"}], "internalType": "struct SpokePoolInterface.RelayerRefundLeaf", "name": "relayerRefundLeaf", "type": "tuple"}, {"internalType": "bytes32[]", "name": "proof", "type": "bytes32[]"}], "name": "executeRelayerRefundLeaf", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "depositor", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "recipient", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "destinationToken", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "totalRelayAmount", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "originChainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "int64", "name": "realizedLpFeePct", "type": "int64"}, {"internalType": "int64", "name": "relayerFeePct", "type": "int64"}, {"internalType": "uint32", "name": "depositId", "type": "uint32"}, {"internalType": "uint32", "name": "rootBundleId", "type": "uint32"}, {"internalType": "bytes", "name": "message", "type": "bytes"}, {"internalType": "int256", "name": "payoutAdjustment", "type": "int256"}, {"internalType": "bytes32[]", "name": "proof", "type": "bytes32[]"}], "name": "executeSlowRelayLeaf", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address"}], "name": "fillCounter", "outputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "depositor", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "recipient", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "destinationToken", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "maxTokensToSend", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "repaymentChainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "originChainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "int64", "name": "realizedLpFeePct", "type": "int64"}, {"internalType": "int64", "name": "relayerFeePct", "type": "int64"}, {"internalType": "uint32", "name": "depositId", "type": "uint32"}, {"internalType": "bytes", "name": "message", "type": "bytes"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "maxCount", "type": "uint256"}], "name": "fillRelay", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "depositor", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "recipient", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "updatedRecipient", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "destinationToken", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "maxTokensToSend", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "repaymentChainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "originChainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "int64", "name": "realizedLpFeePct", "type": "int64"}, {"internalType": "int64", "name": "relayerFeePct", "type": "int64"}, {"internalType": "int64", "name": "updatedRelayerFeePct", "type": "int64"}, {"internalType": "uint32", "name": "depositId", "type": "uint32"}, {"internalType": "bytes", "name": "message", "type": "bytes"}, {"internalType": "bytes", "name": "updatedMessage", "type": "bytes"}, {"internalType": "bytes", "name": "depositorSignature", "type": "bytes"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "maxCount", "type": "uint256"}], "name": "fillRelayWithUpdatedDeposit", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [], "name": "getCurrentTime", "outputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [], "name": "hubPool", "outputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "uint32", "name": "_initialDepositId", "type": "uint32"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "_crossDomainAdmin", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "_hubPool", "type": "address"}], "name": "initialize", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [], "name": "l1Gas", "outputs": [{"internalType": "uint32", "name": "", "type": "uint32"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [], "name": "l2Eth", "outputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [], "name": "messenger", "outputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "bytes[]", "name": "data", "type": "bytes[]"}], "name": "multicall", "outputs": [{"internalType": "bytes[]", "name": "results", "type": "bytes[]"}], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [], "name": "numberOfDeposits", "outputs": [{"internalType": "uint32", "name": "", "type": "uint32"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "bool", "name": "pause", "type": "bool"}], "name": "pauseDeposits", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "bool", "name": "pause", "type": "bool"}], "name": "pauseFills", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [], "name": "pausedDeposits", "outputs": [{"internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [], "name": "pausedFills", "outputs": [{"internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [], "name": "proxiableUUID", "outputs": [{"internalType": "bytes32", "name": "", "type": "bytes32"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "bytes32", "name": "", "type": "bytes32"}], "name": "refundsRequested", "outputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "bytes32", "name": "", "type": "bytes32"}], "name": "relayFills", "outputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "bytes32", "name": "relayerRefundRoot", "type": "bytes32"}, {"internalType": "bytes32", "name": "slowRelayRoot", "type": "bytes32"}], "name": "relayRootBundle", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "refundToken", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "originChainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "destinationChainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "int64", "name": "realizedLpFeePct", "type": "int64"}, {"internalType": "uint32", "name": "depositId", "type": "uint32"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "fillBlock", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "maxCount", "type": "uint256"}], "name": "requestRefund", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256"}], "name": "rootBundles", "outputs": [{"internalType": "bytes32", "name": "slowRelayRoot", "type": "bytes32"}, {"internalType": "bytes32", "name": "relayerRefundRoot", "type": "bytes32"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "newCrossDomainAdmin", "type": "address"}], "name": "setCrossDomainAdmin", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "uint32", "name": "newDepositQuoteTimeBuffer", "type": "uint32"}], "name": "setDepositQuoteTimeBuffer", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "originToken", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "destinationChainId", "type": "uint256"}, {"internalType": "bool", "name": "enabled", "type": "bool"}], "name": "setEnableRoute", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "newHubPool", "type": "address"}], "name": "setHubPool", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "uint32", "name": "newl1Gas", "type": "uint32"}], "name": "setL1GasLimit", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "l2Token", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "tokenBridge", "type": "address"}], "name": "setTokenBridge", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "depositor", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "int64", "name": "updatedRelayerFeePct", "type": "int64"}, {"internalType": "uint32", "name": "depositId", "type": "uint32"}, {"internalType": "address", "name": "updatedRecipient", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "bytes", "name": "updatedMessage", "type": "bytes"}, {"internalType": "bytes", "name": "depositorSignature", "type": "bytes"}], "name": "speedUpDeposit", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address"}], "name": "tokenBridges", "outputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "newImplementation", "type": "address"}], "name": "upgradeTo", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [{"internalType": "address", "name": "newImplementation", "type": "address"}, {"internalType": "bytes", "name": "data", "type": "bytes"}], "name": "upgradeToAndCall", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "payable", "type": "function"}, {"inputs": [], "name": "wrappedNativeToken", "outputs": [{"internalType": "contract WETH9Interface", "name": "", "type": "address"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function"}, {"stateMutability": "payable", "type": "receive"}]

# 创建合约对象
zkSync_SpokePool = w3.eth.contract(address=zkSync_SpokePool_address, abi=zkSync_SpokePool_abi)

# 定义交易参数
transaction_date = {
    'from': 'user_address',
    'value': w3.to_wei(1, 'ether'),  # 存款金额
    'gas': 2000000,
    'gasPrice': w3.to_wei('30', 'gwei'),
}

# 从 API 获取 QUOTE_TIMESTAMP 和 RELAYER_FEE_PCT
response = requests.get('https://across.to/api/suggested-fees?token=0x5AEa5775959fBC2557Cc8789bC1bf90A239D9a91&destinationChainId=10&amount=1000000000000000')
data = json.loads(response.text)
uint32_value_here = data['timestamp']
uint64_value_here = data['relayFeePct']
relayFeePct_uint64 = uint64_value_here
timestamp_uint32 = uint32_value_here



# 从 exchange_amount.txt 文件中读取 AMOUNT
with open(r'F:\web3\Interactive_plan\exchange_amount.txt', 'r') as f:
    exchange_amount = int(f.read().strip())

# 定义 deposit 函数的参数作为一个字典
params = {
    'recipient': 'user_address',
    'origin_token': '0x5AEa5775959fBC2557Cc8789bC1bf90A239D9a91',
    'amount': 1000000000000000,
    'destination_chain_id': 10,
    'relayer_fee_pct': relayFeePct_uint64,
    'quote_timestamp': timestamp_uint32,
    'message': b'',
    'max_count': 1
}

private_key = "User private key"

# 构造交易
transaction = zkSync_SpokePool.functions.deposit(params).buildTransaction(transaction_date)

# 签署交易
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(transaction, private_key)

# 发送交易
txn_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.raw_transaction)

# 等待交易被挖出
txn_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(txn_hash)

print(f"交易哈希: {txn_receipt}")
```

The following error is returned when I execute the code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\web3\Projects\Countracts\Odos_swap1\Across_zks_to_op.py", line 54, in <module>
    transaction = zkSync_SpokePool.functions.deposit(params).buildTransaction(transaction_date)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\web3\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\contract\contract.py", line 238, in __call__
    clone._set_function_info()
  File "F:\web3\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\contract\base_contract.py", line 425, in _set_function_info
    self.abi = find_matching_fn_abi(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\web3\venv\Lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\contracts.py", line 208, in find_matching_fn_abi
    raise Web3ValidationError(message)
web3.exceptions.Web3ValidationError: 
Could not identify the intended function with name `deposit`, positional arguments with type(s) `dict` and keyword arguments with type(s) `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `deposit`: ['deposit(address,address,uint256,uint256,int64,uint32,bytes,uint256)']
Function invocation failed due to improper number of arguments.
```

https://docs.across.to/v/developer-docs/developers/selected-contract-functions#deposit 
This is the API document of the Across project, and I have referred to its content, but right now I'm stuck.

Comment: Check the values you are passing are compatible with the types mentioned in the interface for the function. 
If for example you pass an integer which is too large for a uint64 as fee percent, you could get that error. In your case you seem to be passing a dictionary as the values, and that doesn't seem like what it is asking for.
Have a look at how to call a function method in a contract from web3.py (https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.contract.html#web3.contract.ContractFunction.transact) and maybe practice with something simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I feel is my ABI has a problem, now I'm trying to find 'zksync_spokepool_address: 0 xe0b015e54d54fc84a6cb9b666099c46ade9335ff' contract ABI, Unfortunately, the zksera block browser does not display it, which makes me wonder if it is possible to construct a transaction to complete the interaction with the bridge Across the bridge without using the contract and ABI

Comment: Very welcome. Did you try passing the arguments as individual values, instead of as a dictionary? Like the example is asking for: "deposit(address,address,uint256,uint256,int64,uint32,bytes,uint256)"... You can call contracts without the abi but need to have a real understanding of what you are calling and how to craft the calldata. At this stage you should be using contracts you have the abi for.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

When I change the deposit content to “params = ['0xDepositor','0xRecipient', amount_uint256, chainID_uint256, int(relayFeePct_uint64), int(timestamp_uint32), b"", maxCount_uint256]”, it worked